# restrict inner div to use main div css style class

Tags: css

```
<style type="text/css"> 
   .life-wrapper 
    {
        font-family:lato; 
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold; 
    }

</style>
<div class="life-wrapper">
<div>
  First Inner
   <div id="second">
     Second Inner

    <label>Test Second Inner</label>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here, I have the child div as "second". Here I want to restrict div "second" in such a way that it should not be displayed as parent div design.Here, I don't want to add any new css class for the inner div. I only need to restrict inner div to use main div css class.

Answer (score 1):

Cascading Style Sheets are just that, cascading. So the child elements will inherit from the parents, and so on. The only way to work around it, is to make your "First Inner" text *not to be* a parent of the `#second` element.

As easy as wrapping it into a `<span>First Inner</span>` and setting the style on that: `.life-wrapper span`

```
<style type="text/css"> 
   .life-wrapper span {
        font-family:lato;
        font-size:15px;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>

<div class="life-wrapper">
  <div>
    <span>First Inner</span>
    <div id="second">
      Second Inner
      <label>Test Second Inner</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```